# OpenShift Gears returns different cURL result

Tags: node.js, curl, https, openshift

I have 2 gears in my OpenShift account the first returns an OK (200) response while the other returns a Forbidden (403) response.  Both are sending the same cURL request to the same host.  The main difference in the gears is that one gear is running Node.js and the other is running Python.

This issue is replicated in the json calls to the same host, with the Python gear working (200) and the Node.js gear failing with **(403)** response or **self_signed_cert_in_chain** error depending on how I make the call.

There does not seem to be any information on how to compare the differences between two gears.  Any assistance in working out what the underlying issue is and how I can resolve it so the Node.js application can make json calls would be fabulous.

### Working Gear (Phython) Returns OK (200)

```
curl -d '{}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://cn-dc1.uber.com:443/ --trace-ascii -
== Info: About to connect() to cn-dc1.uber.com port 443 (#0)
== Info:   Trying 104.36.192.190... == Info: connected
== Info: Connected to cn-dc1.uber.com (104.36.192.190) port 443 (#0)
== Info: Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
== Info:   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
== Info: SSL connection using TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
== Info: Server certificate:
== Info:    subject: CN=*.uber.com,OU=Domain Control Validated
== Info:    start date: Apr 21 23:32:02 2014 GMT
== Info:    expire date: Aug 06 23:59:59 2017 GMT
== Info:    common name: *.uber.com
== Info:    issuer: CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - SHA256 - G2,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,C=BE
=> Send header, 230 bytes (0xe6)
0000: POST / HTTP/1.1
0011: User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7
0051:  NSS/3.16.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
008d: Host: cn-dc1.uber.com
00a4: Accept: */*
00b1: Content-Type: application/json
00d1: Content-Length: 2
00e4: 
=> Send data, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: {}
<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<= Recv header, 15 bytes (0xf)
0000: Server: nginx
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Tue, 06 Jan 2015 08:14:47 GMT
<= Recv header, 32 bytes (0x20)
0000: Content-Type: application/json
<= Recv header, 28 bytes (0x1c)
0000: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: Connection: keep-alive
<= Recv header, 69 bytes (0x45)
0000: File-Hashes: locale/messaging.json=a9e6142c96a4ace9494767b208793
0040: 1b3
<= Recv header, 54 bytes (0x36)
0000: File-Hashes: cn.txt=97ac2d5737a3c0768f703a97c465c7ac
<= Recv header, 27 bytes (0x1b)
0000: ReceivedAt: 1420532087986
<= Recv header, 27 bytes (0x1b)
0000: ReturnedAt: 1420532087993
<= Recv header, 25 bytes (0x19)
0000: X-Uber-App: cn_failover
<= Recv header, 44 bytes (0x2c)
0000: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 75 bytes (0x4b)
0000: 40
0004: {"messageType":"Error","description":"Invalid application type"}
0046: 0
0049: 
{"messageType":"Error","description":"Invalid application type"}== Info: Connection #0 to host cn-dc1.uber.com left intact
== Info: Closing connection #0
```

### Failed Gear (Node.js) Returns Forbidden (403)

```
curl -d '{}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://cn-dc1.uber.com:443/ --trace-ascii -
== Info: About to connect() to cn-dc1.uber.com port 443 (#0)
== Info:   Trying 104.36.192.200... == Info: connected
== Info: Connected to cn-dc1.uber.com (104.36.192.200) port 443 (#0)
== Info: Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
== Info:   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
== Info: SSL connection using TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
== Info: Server certificate:
== Info:    subject: CN=*.uber.com,OU=Domain Control Validated
== Info:    start date: Apr 21 23:32:02 2014 GMT
== Info:    expire date: Aug 06 23:59:59 2017 GMT
== Info:    common name: *.uber.com
== Info:    issuer: CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - SHA256 - G2,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,C=BE
=> Send header, 230 bytes (0xe6)
0000: POST / HTTP/1.1
0011: User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7
0051:  NSS/3.16.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
008d: Host: cn-dc1.uber.com
00a4: Accept: */*
00b1: Content-Type: application/json
00d1: Content-Length: 2
00e4: 
=> Send data, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: {}
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
<= Recv header, 15 bytes (0xf)
0000: Server: nginx
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Tue, 06 Jan 2015 08:15:08 GMT
<= Recv header, 25 bytes (0x19)
0000: Content-Type: text/html
<= Recv header, 21 bytes (0x15)
0000: Content-Length: 162
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: Connection: keep-alive
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 162 bytes (0xa2)
0000: <html>
0008: <head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
0033: <body bgcolor="white">
004b: <center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
0074: <hr><center>nginx</center>
0090: </body>
0099: </html>
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
== Info: Connection #0 to host cn-dc1.uber.com left intact
== Info: Closing connection #0
```

### Edit

To rectify the issue with both severs resolving to different IP's I tried the following command with interesting results.

```
curl -d '{}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://104.36.192.191:443/ --trace-ascii -
```

Result from failing server

```
== Info: About to connect() to 104.36.192.191 port 443 (#0)
== Info:   Trying 104.36.192.191... == Info: connected
== Info: Connected to 104.36.192.191 (104.36.192.191) port 443 (#0)
== Info: Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
== Info:   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
== Info: SSL: certificate subject name '*.uber.com' does not match target host name '104.36.192.191'
== Info: NSS error -12276
== Info: Closing connection #0
curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name '*.uber.com' does not match target host name '104.36.192.191'
[node-squirrell.rhcloud.com 54a7f92a5973ca681a00000d]\> timed out waiting for input: auto-logout
Connection to node-squirrell.rhcloud.com closed.
```

Result from OK server

```
== Info: About to connect() to 104.36.192.191 port 443 (#0)
== Info:   Trying 104.36.192.191...
== Info: Adding handle: conn: 0x7fb939804000
== Info: Adding handle: send: 0
== Info: Adding handle: recv: 0
== Info: Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
== Info: - Conn 0 (0x7fb939804000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
== Info: Connected to 104.36.192.191 (104.36.192.191) port 443 (#0)
== Info: SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
== Info: Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

This looks like the ssl / certification libraries are not the same or configured differently between the Python and Node.JS gears.

Comment: The difference is also that the domain name is resolved to another IP. Maybe the uber servers are just set up differently. Try to confirm using IPs instead of domain names (104.36.192.200, 104.36.192.190), each from both gears.

Comment: I also noticed the differing IP's but discounted that Uber would have out of sync servers.  I didn't think to try curl using IP's though.  I have added the results to the question and it looks like it might point to SSL library issues.  I will check further tomorrow. Thanks @ptrk

Answer (score 0):

The failing one (with IPs) seems just to break on the name mismatch. There's one more hint: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=cn-dc1.uber.com&latest
says that the cert chain may contain an extra downloadable intermediate cert, and your app might not support it. You might need to add it to your nodejs keystore.